# What is the difference between variable name and pointers?

Tags: c++, c, variables, pointers

Consider this example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

Somebody told me in the above code, first a block of memory for integer is created and assigned value 5 and then **a** points to that block. And then, **b** also points to the same block of memory containing value 5.

So my question is if **a** is an integer variable and it also points to something then how does it differ from a pointer?

Pardon me if this question is too basic. But I need to know.

Comment: a pointer is a variable that stores the memory address of some other data. that's all. that's it. a pointer IS a variable with a very specific usage. neither of your vars above are pointers. memory is assigned to store the `5`, but that's not a pointer.

Comment: Don't confuse *the letter "a"* with *the variable called "a"*.

Comment: A better phrase might be "a is the name for that block of memory".

Comment: @MarcB A pointer doesn't have to be a variable. With the example from the OPs code, `&a` is a pointer but isn't a variable, and neither is `(char *) 0xffff0000`.

Comment: Someone told me that "my house" means the house at 123 Fake St. So if my house just points to another house, what's the difference between a house and an address? (Answer: This question makes no sense, because I'm deliberately conflating the words "my" "house", and the actual house)

Comment: Please read some C and C++ books (maybe an assembler book, too)

Comment: Your question `how does it differ from a pointer? ` has no answer, because it contains a false assumption: `...and it also points to something`. It doesn't.

Comment: can someone please explain me what is actually happening in the memory for the above code?

Comment: The somebody is wrong - there are 2 'blocks' of memory allocated, one for `a` and one for `b`. If you add `a = 6;` just before the return, then `a` and `b` have different values.

Comment: @DieterLücking IMO this is an intelligible, well-formed question a person can have while reading a book -- even if it's based on a false premise, there was research involved.

Comment: @Litty Not really. Most books will make it clear that a and b are separate memory locations. Failing that, a very quick and trivial test will confirm it.

Comment: @JBentley ... if they represent memory-locations at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whoever explained this to you is wrong in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 5; //variable a has value 5 put it
    //a does have an address
    int b = a; 
    //variable b is created, it has its own seperate memory address.
    //in this case the CONTENTS of a (5) are dumped inside b
    return 0;
}
```

saying `int b=a;` will not make the variables aliases of each other.

What you heard about is this:

```
//...
int a=1;
int *b = &a; //create a pointer called b and make it point to a 
//(set it equal to address of a)
```

in your case you have:

```
memory addresses:         variable name           value stored at memory address
1000                      a(int)                    5
1004                      b(int)                    5
```

obviously changing values of a and does not affect each other

in the case I described you have this:

```
memory addresses:         variable name           value stored at memory address
1000                      a(int)                    5
1004                      b(int*)                   1000
```

as you can see, since `b` is a pointer, its actual value is the address of a.

so doing `*b=3;` will change the value of `a`

Comment: Note: the variable names are not stored in memory.

Comment: @user253751 where are they stored?

Comment: @AndreasK. They are not. They are only something the compiler looks at.

Answer (score 5):

When you declare

```
int a = 1;
```

Compiler allocate memory for `sizeof(int)` bytes and name that data location (or memory block) `a` and place a value `1` in that block. 
In a very simple way a variable is a named location of data.

You can think of it as putting the value assigned in a box with the variable name as [shown](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/) below:
[image]

And for all the variables you create a new box is created with the variable name to hold the value.

Assigning one variable to another makes a copy of the value and put that value in the new box.

```
a = 2;
int b = a;
```

[image] [image]

So, `a` and `b` are not pointers but are the names of different memory blocks having their own addresses.

Answer (score 3):

What you may be thinking of is (if this is in a C++ context):

```
int a = 5;
int& b = a;
```

This creates a *reference* to `a` which is bound to the memory of `a`.

Changing `b` now alters `a`:

```
b = 42;
if (a == 42) // true
```

In your OP that wouldn't be the case since `b` there is a separate variable independent to `a`.

Comment: Should be noted that this is a C++ answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing compile-time and run-time concepts.

Names in a C program are compile-time entities that refer to storage that will be used at runtime.  Once the compiler finishes its work, and you have object code, the names are gone (except for debug info, which isn't really part of the runtime object code -- its extra info for a debugger to refer to), and your object code directly operates on values in registers or memory (the 'storage' I referred to above).

We usually say "refers to" instead of "points at" even though the english meaning of those words is pretty much the same, as "points at" make one think of pointers, which are a completely different run-time concept.

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, `a` and `b` are separate variables sitting in their own block of memory.

This line:

```
int a = 5;
```

Creates a variable named `a` and gives it an initial value of `5`.

This line:

```
int b = a;
```

Created a variable named `b` and gives it an initial value of whatever the current value of `a` is, in this case `5`.

If you were to later add the line `a=4`, `a` would contain the value `4` while `b` will still contain the value `5`.

Answer (score 1):

> can someone please explain me what is actually happening in the memory for the above code?

I'll make up some addresses - let's say a is at 1000 and b is at 1004.

At first, there are leftover values from whatever last used that area of memory. That could be anything:

```
Address     Value
  ...
  1000      1234
  1004      5678
  ...
```

Then `int a = 5;` sets the space reserved for `a` to 5.

```
Address     Value
  ...
  1000      5
  1004      5678
  ...
```

Then `int b = a;` copies that to the space reserved for `b`:

```
Address     Value
  ...
  1000      5
  1004      5
  ...
```

At no point are the variable names actually involved.

The variable names are used *by the compiler only*. In this case, the compiler knows that "`a`" means "the value at address 1000" and that "`b`" means "the value at address 1004". (That's slightly oversimplified, since local variables aren't always stored at the same address, but you get the idea)

Comment: No `a` doesn't mean "the value at address X", it depends if `a` is used as a left-value or a right-value.

Comment: "At first, there are leftover values from whatever last used that area of memory" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: @user132458 That means the memory could contain anything. Your code might not be the first code to use the addresses 1000 and 1004. (But it might be, since each process has its own address space, meaning your address 1000 is different from another process's address 1000)

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
int a = 5;
```

`a` denotes a container in which 5 is stored. `a` is just an identifier to represent either the memory location or its content. In `a=5`, `a` denotes the container, in `5+a`,  `a` denotes the value contained.

In:

```
int b = a;
```

`b` denotes a container in which the current value of the container `a` is stored.

Then you have 2 containers, one denoted `a` and the other denoted `b`. Both contains a value (the same for both).

Neither of these to variables are pointers. But, as every variable in C, they have address that is obtained with operator `&`. `&a` is the address of the container `a`.

A pointer is a variable (a container if you wish) whose value is the address of some container. Thus:

```
int *p = &a;
```

`p` is a container that contains the address of `a`, we shortly say `p` points to `a`. And of course `p` also has an address (as every variable/container): `&p`.